# How to smoothly rename a Phoenix Project?

Tags: git, sed, elixir, phoenix-framework, xargs

I've cloned a `git` repo and I need to start a new project based off of it.

How do I rename it, making sure everything is taken care of?

I'm using **macOS**.

Comment: I usually just do a search-replace of `MyApp` with `MyNewApp`, `my_app` with `my_new_app`, rename `lib/my_app` to `lib/my_new_app`, check if it still compiles and finally manually review `git diff`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that doesn't take care of renaming the application and internal references in the code.

Comment: @Dogbert would you care to explicitly show the commands you're using?

Comment: For search-replace in the command line, I'm a fan of Perl: `git ls-files | xargs perl -p -i -e 's/MyApp/MyNewApp/g ; s/my_app/my_new_app/g'` (make sure your changes are committed before running this!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of [nerdyworm's rename.sh](https://gist.github.com/nerdyworm/3d623b13bf0d6d664373e2f501f16423), that uses `ack` I've adapted it to use `git grep` and run on **macOS** easily.

• **OTP NAME**: Snake Case (snake_case) name for the Application.

• **NAME**: Regular app name.

```
$ git grep -l $CURRENT_OTP | xargs sed -i '' -e "s/$CURRENT_OTP/$NEW_OTP/g"
$ git grep -l $CURRENT_NAME | xargs sed -i '' -e "s/$CURRENT_NAME/$NEW_NAME/g"

$ mv lib/$CURRENT_OTP lib/$NEW_OTP
$ mv lib/$CURRENT_OTP.ex lib/$NEW_OTP.ex
```

Comment: Anything that would need to be changed for renaming a Phoenix 1.3 project?

Comment: @Emily not sure I understood your question, this process works regardless of Phoenix's version (tested on 1.2.x and 1.3.x).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to do this automatically with perfect accuracy, but these are the steps I follow manually when I need to rename Phoenix projects.

The commands below assume your code is in a `git` repo and the old application is `my_app` / `MyApp` and the new one is `my_new_app` / `MyNewApp`. The process is brittle -- if your application or module name can occur in many places (e.g. it's a single letter `A` or something), then this will not work.

```
# search replace both the application name and module name in all files indexed by git
$ git ls-files -z | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e 's/my_app/my_new_app/g; s/MyApp/MyNewApp/g;'
# rename `lib/my_app`
$ mv lib/my_app lib/my_new_app
```

After that I run `mix test` and fix any compilation errors or test failures.

Finally I do a quick review of `git diff` to make sure everything looks right.

Comment: `lib/my_app.ex` was not caught by the pattern somehow (the filename, not the content of the file)

Comment: I used this method and it worked well, but I also experienced the issue mentioned by @jaysoifer - it was easy enough to fix that, though.